# Is a iframe src requested from the user's ip address or the website servers ip address?

Tags: html, iframe, ip-address, ip

Is a iframe src requested from the user's ip address or the website servers ip address?

I suspect this is from a users IP, but can anyone confirm?

Thanks,

- Dane

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to up-vote the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) content is requested from the user side (e.g. by the browser).

P.S. The website server would request content if it was doing some sort of server side include (which has nothing to do with iframes but is a feature of some web frameworks depending on the web server and the framework itself). An example of this is [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) `include` directive or EmbPer's `Execute()`. In that case the user's browser wouldn't even see the included URL, but only the content included into the HTML by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is requested by the users's browser.

It is just like you say the browser to read a website like any other but then to display it within the iframe borders.

Answer (score 0):

iframe tag is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.Yes,it requests webcontent from user's side.

```
enter code here
<card>
<iframe src="https://www.w3school.com">
</card>
```

[Screenshot for Iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5m5S.png)